# when I'm entering user input it is displaying on the pdf page but when I'm clearing the input it's not clearing on the pdf as well

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to make a pdf previewer.

whenever any user enter their value it should display on pdf on real time parallely.
the problem is when user input something it is shown on pdf but when user clears the input it's not clearing on the pdf as well.

```js
let pdfPreview = document.getElementById("pdf");
let inputName = document.getElementById("name");
let clear = document.getElementById("btn");

let doc = new jsPDF({
  orientation: "landscape",
});

doc.setFontSize(15);
doc.text(20, 50, "Name__________________");
doc.text(20, 65, "Roll No_____________");

let pdfData = doc.output();

// function for rendering pdf
let blow = (data) => {
  let pdfBlob = new Blob([data], {
    type: "application/pdf",
  });

  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
  console.log(objectURL);
  pdfPreview.setAttribute("src", objectURL)
};

blow(pdfData);

inputName.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // window.location.reload();
  doc.text(39, 50, `${inputName.value}`);
  blow(doc.output());
});

clear.addEventListener("click", () => {
  element = doc.text(60, 50, "");
  pdfData = doc.output();
  doc.removeOption(pdfData);
  blow(pdfData);
});
```

```css
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 70px;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="form-control">
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" >
                <label for="roll">Roll No</label>
                <input type="text" id="roll">
            </form>
            <button id="btn">Clear</button>
        </div>
        <!-- PDF Previewer -->
        <iframe src="" id="pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

whenever any user enter their value it should display on pdf on real time parallely.
the problem is when user input something it is shown on pdf but when user clears the input it's not clearing on the pdf as well. Please try to provide me good solution.

I was expecting to make a pdf fully editable. if user input anything render on pdf if users clears it render on pdf.

Comment: Can't test this because it doesn't want to run properly in the snippet (blob content is getting blocked by security settings) - but I am guessing your mistake is a misunderstanding of how the `text` method works. This draws text at a given position in your PDF, yes - but you can't _erase_ that text by simply drawing "nothing" over it. You will probably need to work with saveGraphicsState and restoreGraphicsState here.

Comment: Can you please try running it on local environment.

Comment: Why, I doubt that will change anything about what I said.

Comment: @CBroe like you said work with saveGraphics state and restoreGraphicsState its not working